# Daily quota for post submissions

Tags: form

How would you go about creating a daily quota for posts? I have a simple photo gallery where users can submit images, problem is some people are a bit too excited. I'd like to limit submission to let's say 10 per day per user. Any tips how to approach this welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to hide the button or page where users could upload a photo.

To do this you could query for all that users entries with today's postDate. If the total is equal to or more than 10 then you'd redirect them to a different page or hide/disable the button that submits an entry.

Something along the lines of the following

`add-image.twig`

```
{% set todaysEntryCount = craft.entries.section( 'images' ) authorId( currentUser.id ).postDate( '> ' ~ now|date_modify('-1 day') ).total() %}
{% if daysEntryCount >= 10 %}
  {% redirect /your-images?message=dailylimit %}
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if daysEntryCount < 10 %}
   <button type="submit">Add your image</button>
{% endif %}
```